# Launch App from iTunes

Tags: iphone

I am launching an iTunes from my App, from where when I buy or install an app it is redirecting me to the device menu where I can see the app downloading, but my requirement is when I buy/install an app. from iTunes it should redirect to the app again from where the app is terminated instead of menu. Please help me out on this.... Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no public available method for having iTunes automatically launch your app after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please let the device have your app before you start executing your code. Assuming there was no sandboxing on the platform, even then how would iTunes know that it had to launch your app if it has not yet been installed.